# Concat javascript files under a single file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

File structure.

```
/app 
  /components 
     /core 
        /extensions
           - array.js 
           - string.js
        /services
           - logger.js 
        /lib 
           - core.js
```

**Core.js**

```
(function() {
     'use strict';
     angular.module('app.core',[]);  
}());
```

What i need is to  overwrite core.js on each build by copying all the other js files in that folder on to it, while keeping this first original content of the module deceleration.

This is the wanted result for Core.js :

```
(function() {
     'use strict';
     angular.module('app.core',[]);  
}());
// content of array.js
(function() {
   'use strict';

    var core = angular.module('app.core');
    core.config( .....) 
 }());     

 // content of string.js
 ...
 // content of logger.js
```

Iv'e tried 2 grunt tasks which i believed where men't for this purpose but did not find a way the configure them to my needs.

1) grunt-concat had 2 issues the first that it appends the contents from the start of the file and not the end of the file like i wanted. and it does not override the existing content.

2) grunt-copy does override but it overrides the entire file.

What iv'e attempted is to use the process function for grunt copy.

```
  copy: {
      src: ['app/components/core/{,*/}*.js'],
      dest: 'app/components/core/lib/core.js',
      options:{
          process : function(content, srcpath){
              return content; // do some manipulation on content here. 
          }
      }         
  }
```

This is also problematic since i would have to keep the text that comprises the angular module definition in my Gruntfile and append it to the first content that comes into my process function, something like this which seems really messy.

```
 process : function(content, srcpath){
              if(isFirst) {
                  isFirst = false;
                  // here i will append the angular module deceleration. 
              }
              return content;
          }
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve what iv'e described ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grunt-contrib-concat` is exactly what you need, just do the following:

1. rename your current `core.js` to `_banner.js` (or anything you like) - it's a good practice to not overwrite your banner file anyway
2. setup `concat` to agregate `_banner.js` then your other files, and save it as `core.js`:

   ```
   concat: {
     core: {
       files: [{
         src: [
           'app/components/core/_banner.js',
           'app/components/core/extensions/*.js',
           'app/components/core/services/*.js'
         ],
         dest: 'app/components/core/lib/core.js'
       }]
     },
   },
   ```

Should give you what you want

Comment: i  thought so as well but i have 2 issues with grunt concat as iv'e stated in my question above. i would have to first some how clean the file completely since it will concatenate every thing every time. the second is that it concatenates to the start of the file and not the end of the file

Comment: files :[ ... ] tries to create a directory with files under core.js which fails. 
what you did teach me is that i can control the order of the concatenation using an array of sources.  

i still have the problem that i need to some how clean my core.js file before the next concat.

Comment: I would advise **not** to use the same file as input and output (core.js) - that way cleaning and start/end of file problems go away : delete core.js (use grunt-contrib-clean), then re-generate from your files.

Comment: and I edited my answer to fix the issue of grunt creating a `core.js` directory (caused by my `expand:true` option)

Comment: it turns out concat is smart enough to diff between the current core.js and the next concat attempt. i accedently copied core.js again on to itself.